# When would I use a Static Object reference

Tags: java

I have been coding in Java for sometime and I understand the difference between Static and non static methods. But I recently came across static Object reference

```
 private static Work workTwo = new Work();
```

What is the need for a static object reference and under what case should I include them in my code

Comment: `private static final Logger logger` seems rather common.

Comment: Same as for a method: when you want it to belong to the class itself rather than an instance of it.

Comment: `static final` constants for a class that may be used by all objects from that class

Answer (score 0):

Use it when the semantics are what you need.  Specifically when you want the value to exist only once and be shared across all instances of the class, or the entire application.  `static final` is good for immutable constants (eg numbers or strings).

See also: 
[Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil?rq=1)